# Should I have index with all Where-clause fields?

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, b-tree-index

I have a table, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE films (
    title       varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    did         integer NOT NULL,
    date_prod   date,
    kind        varchar(10)
);
```

I have a index, like this:

```
CREATE INDEX films_title_kind_idx ON films (title, kind);
```

I have a query, like this:

```
SELECT title, did, kind, date_prod 
FROM films
WHERE title = 'title1' AND
      kind = 'kind2' AND
      did = 4;
```

Should I create index with 3 columns? Or current index **films_title_kind_idx**  is enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Depends.**

A reasonable rule of thumb is that an index is useful if it always matches less than ten percent of the records. Assuming this is really a movie database, an index for `title, kind` or even just `title` will return a very small record set for further filtering. I can't be sure because I don't know what `did` is (probably not a good field name), but if it has many values, it would be reasonable to add it into the composite index.

Comment: will Postgresql use index for 2 fields, when I select with 3-field clause?

Comment: Yes. If you index A,B and your query has A,B,C in the WHERE clause, it will use the index, and it will also then filter on C. Postgres is smart, it will also use an index on A,B,Q for a query on A,B,C.

Comment: oh, great news. I thought, that Postgres may use index and may not.

Comment: You should look at `EXPLAIN` and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`; PG will tell you if it is using indexes. If it isn't then either you need to re-run `ANALYZE`, or it's analyzed but guesses that the index isn't helpful, not selective enough.